# Python get only values in each dictionary

Tags: python, json, key-value

I intend to get the values for each dictionary in array list and put the values in new dictionary.

There are two key,two values in each dictionary.

This is my array_list.

```
[{'Name': 'email', 
'Value': 'mail@outlook.com'}, 
{'Name': 'name', 
'Value': 'tester'}, 
{'Name': 'address', 
'Value': 'abc'}]
```

My expected outcome (to get the both values in each dictionary):

```
{'email': 'mail@outlook.com',
 'name': 'tester', 
'address': 'abc'}
```

My current code:

```
outcome = {}
x = ""

for i in range(len(array_list)):
    for key,value in array_list[i].items():
        if key == 'Value':
            x = value
        elif key == 'Name': 
            outcome[value] = x
```

I still not able to get the expected outcome. Any helps?

Comment: Better to ask dictionary `array_list[i]` directly with e.g. `array_list[i]['Name']` instead of iterating over its items.

Comment: The reason you don't get the correct output is that it will only work if the Name is encountered _after_ the Value. It is also inefficient as you should be looking up the keys in the dict instead of iterating until you stumble into them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = [{'Name': 'email', 
'Value': 'mail@outlook.com'}, 
{'Name': 'name', 
'Value': 'tester'}, 
{'Name': 'address', 
'Value': 'abc'}]

{k['Name'] : k['Value'] for k in l}
```

the result is

```
{'address': 'abc', 'email': 'mail@outlook.com', 'name': 'tester'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost correct. Just have some problems in if else.

After writing a code you should try to simulate your code by yourself. Please look carefully in you inner for loop. For each iteration either Name or Value will be set as if and elif is mutually exclusive. But the requirement is to create key-value in each iteration.

```
outcome = {}
array_list = [{'Name': 'email',
               'Value': 'mail@outlook.com'},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Value': 'tester'},
              {'Name': 'address',
               'Value': 'abc'}]
for i in range(len(array_list)):
    keys = array_list[i].keys()
    if 'Name' in keys and 'Value' in keys:
        outcome[array_list[i]['Name']] = array_list[i]['Value']
```

It is almost same as your code but my thinking is different.